# Behavior of SIO_FLUSH

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, ioctl

When SIO_FLUSH socket ioctl is used in a Windows environment (in user space), I am confused as to what happens.  Does this: (1) completely discard the data from the TCP/IP send queue into a black hole, or (2) push the queued send data across the connection until the buffer is empty, or (3) something else?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Windows, you can never be sure. 
However, [this](http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/sock2/SOCK2WSAIoctl.htm)(search for SIOFLUSH) says it discards the send queue associated with the socket. This is what I also expect when I use SIO_FLUSH

Comment: Note that you can also find this information in the [official Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ms741621(v=vs.71)), but it's rather hard to find. Rather frustratingly, there are several near duplicate pages that only mention SIO_FLUSH but don't say anything about what it actually does.